# Risk of Insulation Tester / Megger damage from voltage breakdowns?

Tags: high-voltage, insulation, insulation-voltage

I've purchased an insulation tester capable of outputting 5kV and measuring resistance up to 1000 GΩ, as detailed in the manual available [here](https://rishabh.co.in/uploads/product/AIT_501_Instruction_Manual.pdf).

While my tests are not prone to significant breakdowns, I am curious about the behavior in scenarios involving high-value resistors (> 100 MΩ) when subjected to the full 5kV potential. What is the likelihood of damaging the meter when such resistors breaking down and potentially arcing?

The manual notes a "`Short Circuit Maximum than 2.0mA`" specification. Does this limit apply in the case of insulation failure, and are insulation testers usually designed to handle such events without damage?

Comment: In the linked manual after Figure 5 it is written: Do not measure over 10 seconds: measuring resistance ＜20MΩ with use of 5000V. That means 0.25 mA or less is ok, therefore nominal power is 5kV * 0.25mA = 1.25 W. A breakdown will fall below these 20MΩ. And I assume either the shunt (measuring the current) or the 5-kV power supply could damage in short circuit. An isolation measurement device should be prepared for such breakdowns, so I am quite surprised, that the operator has to stop measuring latest 10s after a breakdown - perhaps a design of a "breakdown protection circuit" is difficult.

Comment: Why would a tester damage when normal testing operations are being performed? Aren't insulation testers supposed to be used to test when insulation breaks down?

Comment: I conducted an experiment using the nets of the fly zapper, which has gaps between three nets. It's known that applying about 3kV or more leads to air breakdown mostly influenced by moisture and particle count. When  the voltage tester is connected, readings were stable up to 2500V. However, at 5kV, an arc resulted from the air breakdown, causing the meter to shut off with a long beep - indicating that the meter didn't like the event? On a side-note, this caused EMI significant enough to disconnect USB devices on my PC, despite all being equipped with ferrite beads and shielded cables!